# save select field on checkout page woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, customization

I'm new to WooCommerce.I'm unable to figure out where is problem here is my code

I have added a select field in billing form of checkout page.

**Problem**

records are not saving or updating on submitting. Problem is in Update the order meta with field value.value is not updating in database

```
// checkout page customization start

global $post, $woocommerce; 
// Account select field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields($fields) {

     $fields['billing']['Account'] = array(
'type'          => 'select',
'class'         => array('billing form-row-wide'),
'label'         => __('Choose an Account'),
'placeholder'   => _x('Account', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
'options'     => array(
                    '' => __( 'Select Account','' ),              
                    ),
'required'    => true,
 );
  return $fields;

}



add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');
function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
global $woocommerce;

if (!$_POST['Account'])
$woocommerce->add_error( __('Please enter your Account.'.$_POST['Account']));
}
///**
```

**Problem area** 
value is not updating in database

```
//* Update the order meta with field value
//**/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
if ($_POST['Account']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Account',      esc_attr($_POST['Account']));
}

/**
* Update the user meta with field value
**/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_user_meta');
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_user_meta( $user_id ) {
if ($user_id && $_POST['Account']) update_user_meta( $user_id, 'Account', esc_attr($_POST['Account']) );
}
```

Comment: You need to associate the account to the Post?, Now if you check the wp_usermeta table in DB,  is updating each time i change the account option in checkout, At Least that's happens in my test.

Answer (score 0):

The functions look pretty accurate to me. Are you sure they aren't updating? Or perhaps you are having difficulty is displaying them.

I've tweaked them a bit. First, to use the `$posted` variabled that WooCommerce sends to the function, though this is trivial as `$_POST` should be the same. And secondly, you are using [`esc_attr()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr) when you should be using [`sanitize_text_field()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_text_field). The former is for displaying the data in an HTML attribute while the latter is for sanitizing before saving.

```
//* Update the order meta with field value
//**/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 10, 2 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id, $posted ) {
    if ( isset( $posted['Account'] ) ){
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Account', sanitize_text_field( $posted['Account'] ) );
    }
}

/**
* Update the user meta with field value
**/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_user_meta', 10, 2 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_user_meta( $user_id, $posted ) {
    if ( $user_id && isset( $posted['Account'] ) ){
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'Account', sanitize_text_field( $posted['Account'] ) );
    } 
}
```